# Recover database to previous after it is restored from backup file

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database `db1`. I backup this database two days ago and it is stored as `db1.bak`.

Now I created another database `db2` and restored using backup file `db1.bak`. I made changes to many tables in `db2`.

Today due to some reasons I restored `db2` using `db1.bak` without taking backup of `db2` :(

But now I need to recover database `db2` with the rows as of yesterday. I guess this is not possible but for a try I'm posting here.

Note: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

If anyone knows the way to recover, kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no magic backup fairy; you data is gone.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. You have lost the changes